# Nodejs - Get remote file contents using custom network Interface

Tags: node.js, interface, ip

I have a machine with a whole ip block allotted.
I want to call a remote URL to get its contents.
I want to be able to choose which interface/ip address should the call originate from.

For ex.
I have ip addreses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.9
and remote file is "http://www.google.com/robots.txt"
and another remote file is "http://www.yahoo.com/robots.txt"

I want the first url google.com/robots.txt to be called via my ip 8.8.8.8
and the second url yahoo.com/robots.txt via my ip 8.8.8.9

I am using the request.get method.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a http request in node you can set interface to with localaddress: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

```
  var options = {
    localaddress: '8.8.8.8',
    hostname: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': postData.length
    }
    var callback = function (res, err) { ...do something... }
    http.request(options, callback)
```

Comment: If your happy with the answer then it would be nice if you marked it as the correct answer. ;)

Comment: i did that. it says i need a reputation of some 15 to make it public